# Ruby/Rails: Is there a way to modify a datetime_field in a view so that only minutes multiples of 15 can be selected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these two lines in one of my views:

```
   <%= form.label :time, style: "display: block" %>
   <%= form.datetime_field :time%>
```

It allows you to choose any time for the :time variable (DateTime type).

I am looking to limit it so that only the options of 0, 15, 30 or 45 minutes are shown, is there a way to do this without having to use validations?

Comment: use `minute_step` as an option... e.g. `form.date_time_field, :time, minute_step: 15`

Answer (score 3):

In the native datetime input, minute selection is not possible. However, you can use Rails' [time_select](https://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper#time_select-instance_method) method with the `:minute_step` option:

```
<%= form.time_select :time, { minute_step: 15 } %>
```

You can also use the `:start_hour` and `:end_hour` options to limit the range of hours. E.g.:

```
<%= form.time_select :time, { minute_step: 15, start_hour: 9, end_hour: 17 } %>
```

This will restrict the hour selection from 9am to 5pm, with 15 minute intervals.

Comment: It works for me, but can I choose a range of hours so that only those within show?

Comment: You can. Hold on, I'll update my answer.